# Proving that two random variables are not independent

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Consider two random variables

$$ X \sim N(0,1), \: Y := X^2 $$

I want to prove that these are not independent. However, I'm unable to find their joint cumulative distribution function (cdf) to show that the joint cdf does not factor into the individual cdfs.

1. How do I find the joint cdf?
2. Is there any other way to show they are not independent?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{erf}{\operatorname{erf}}$It is quite clear that $P(X<-3\land X^2<2)=0\ne P(X<-3)P(X^2<2)$. However, if you want the joint cdf, it is \begin{align}F(x,y)&=P(X\le x\land X^2\le y)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }y<0\\ P\left(X\le x\land -\sqrt y\le X\le \sqrt y\right)&\text{if }y\ge0\end{cases}=\\&=\begin{cases} \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\sqrt y}^{\min(x,\sqrt y)}e^{-t^2/2}\,dt&\text{if }y\ge0\land x\ge-\sqrt y\\ 0&\text{if }y<0\lor \left(y\ge 0\land x<-\sqrt y\right)\end{cases}=\\&=\begin{cases} \frac12\erf\left(\frac{\min(x,\sqrt y)}{\sqrt2}\right)-\frac12\erf\left(-\sqrt{\frac{y}{2}}\right)&\text{if }y\ge0\land x\ge-\sqrt y\\ 0&\text{if }y<0\lor \left(y\ge 0\land x<-\sqrt y\right)\end{cases}\end{align}

Comment: What is the wedge-like symbol that you use and what does it mean?

Comment: @sixtyTonneAngel $\land$ is logical "and", $\lor$ is logical "or".